Trino SQL Server Connector Procedure Error
I am trying to utilize the system.execute procedure from the Trino SQL Server Connector here and am running into issues: https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/sqlserver.html
Trino CALL documentation here:https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/call.html
I am working with Trino in DBT and have a SQL Server connector set. In my model, I have
{{  config(     catalog=“sqlserver”,     schema=“test” ) }}  with test as ( CALL system.execute(query=>’ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_FunctionName NEXT USED [PRIMARY]’) )  Select 1

I am getting the error

Mismatched input CALL. Expecting: ‘<query>’”.

Are there any ideas as to what the issue is? I tried running
CALL system.execute(query=\>’ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_FunctionName NEXT USED \[PRIMARY\]’)

in starburst directly and got the error

mismatched input “execute”. Expecting ‘<identifer>’

After doing some more digging I realized I needed to utilize the dbt call block. My code now looks like the following
{{
config(
    catalog=“sqlserver”,
    schema=“test”
)
}}

{% call statement() %}
CALL system.execute(query=>’ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_FunctionName NEXT USED [PRIMARY]’)
)
{% endcall %}

I am now just getting the following error (same as just running the call in starburst):

mismatched input ‘execute’. Expecting: ‘<identifer>’

Side note based on a question below: I am not selecting anything currently because I just need to update a global partition before I load data, I will select a timestamp value here, but I don’t believe that’s the issue

The documentation you link is about calling a stored procedure - ,maybe try CALL sys.sp_executesql('ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_FunctionName NEXT USED [PRIMARY]')?

Or look at EXECUTE maybe? https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/execute.html
